# Как оптимально перенести записи с одной таблицы в другую таблицу?

Tags: sql, oracle, оптимизация

В таблице B есть 2 миллиона записей. Когда пытаюсь перенести в таблицу A обычной вставкой из запроса, занимает очень много времени.

Нужен более оптимальный вариант, чем:

```
INSERT 
INTO A
(
   NAME,
   LASTNAME,
   AGE
)
SELECT
   b.NAME,
   b.LASTNAME,
   b.AGE
FROM B b
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте с [Direct-Path INSERT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admin/managing-tables.html#GUID-134D6EB6-219E-4820-AB54-8C60067A8F0F). Включить его можно подсказкой `APPEND`:

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO A (NAME, LASTNAME, AGE)
    SELECT b.NAME, b.LASTNAME, b.AGE
    FROM B b
```

Comment: можете сказать что такое /*+ APPEND */

Comment: @TeonaNadiradze APPEND это подсказка для оптимизатора, она включит "прямую запись" в таблицу.